# Permutation question based on recursion

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, recurrence-relations, recursion

> Let $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ be a permutation of the numbers $1,2,\ldots,n$ such that $\forall 1 \leq k \leq n-1$, $ \quad a_1,a_2,\ldots a_k$ is NOT a permutation of $1,2,\ldots,k$.
>   Determine the number of permutations possible.

I first noted that for n=1, no permutations exist and for n=2 one such permutation exists . I tried to create a recursion relation, somewhat like principle of inclusion and exclusion but I kept getting it incorrect (It didn't satisfy for small values of n).

Comment: Is this a programming challenge?

Comment: There is one permutation for $n=1$ because the condition becomes $1 \le k \le 0$.  You also lost a $k$ in your expression following $\forall$

Comment: There is one permutation for $n=1$.

Comment: How many admissible permutations have $1$ last?  How many have $1$ next-to-last?

Comment: If 1 is last there are (n-1)! permutations. If 1 is next to last there are (n-1)!-(n-2)! permutations. (but proceeding for general case this approach wouldn't work isn't?)

Comment: I'm not sure.  I was just suggesting an approach.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A003319

Answer (score 2):

HINT

Lets call a permutation with this property *good*, and a permutation without this property *bad*.

By definition, any *bad* permutation $\pi$ has some $k$ where $a_1, \dots, a_k$ is a permutation of $1, \dots, k$.  This also means there is a **smallest** such $k$ for this $\pi$, which we will call $\pi$'s badness number.

- How many bad permutations of size $n$ has a badness number of $k$?

Can you finish from here?  Remember to check your answer against http://oeis.org/A003319 as @saulspatz suggested.